# VBA Auto-Hide based on Condition Immediate

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to auto-hide entire rows based on conditions but I want it to automatically do this and not just when I open the workbook. I am stuck.

```
Sub vba_hide_row_columns()

Dim i As Integer
    For i = 4 To 9000
    If Cells(i, 5).Value = "Complete" Or Cells(i, 5).Value = "Discontinued" Then
        Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next i
    
End Sub
```

Please help

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean by "automatically" then? Something has to trigger it... either a button you press or an event that happens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/worksheet-object-events

Comment: Yes, if I enter "Complete" in Column 5, hide the entire row. That would be the event. I don't want to wait until I close the workbook or open it. I want it to hide the row while I am still in there.

Comment: Then you want the `Worksheet_Change` event - There you can check to see which cell changed and make adjustments as needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: But, how do I write it? I keep getting an error.

Comment: VBasic2008 has written the code for you. Just copy/paste his answer. If you have problem with it, then leave a comment on his answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change: Hide/Show Entire Rows

- This is ideal when you have dropdowns in the critical column so you don't have to type it.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1` (Mandatory)**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With Me.Range("E4")
        Set rg = Intersect(.Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
    End With
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim rgHide As Range, rgShow As Range, cell As Range, rStr As String
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        rStr = CStr(cell.Value)
        Select Case LCase(rStr)
            Case "complete", "discontinued" ' in lowercase to ignore the case
                Set rgHide = RefCombinedRanges(rgHide, cell)
            Case Else
                Set rgShow = RefCombinedRanges(rgShow, cell)
        End Select
    Next cell
    
    If Not rgHide Is Nothing Then rgHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If Not rgShow Is Nothing Then rgShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1` (Optionally in the e.g. `Sheet1` Module)**

```vb
Function RefCombinedRanges( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRanges = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRanges = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, thank you so much for the above. I do get a Compile error: Sub or Function not defined. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need both bits of code that @VBasic2008 posted.  The first bit of code is a _procedure_ that fires when you change a value on the sheet.  That code then uses the RefCombinedRanges _function_  to stick the found ranges together.